# Problems reading stdin in node child process

Tags: node.js, process, stdin

I'm trying to execute a command in windows using nodes child_process module. The problem is that the application in question (ftp command line in windows) prompts for a username and password. I tried to provide the command with the asked information in the following way:

```
var ftp = spawn('ftp',['<<ip of server>>']); 
var authenticated = false;
var commandsSended = false;

ftp.stdin.write("debug\n");
ftp.stdin.write(os.EOL);

ftp.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log("FTPService: " + data.toString());
    if(data.toString().indexOf("226 Transfer complete") > -1) {
        ftp.stdin.write('bye\n');
    } else if(data.toString().indexOf("Gebruiker") > -1) {
        ftp.stdin.write("<<username of server>>");
        ftp.stdin.write(os.EOL);
    } else if(data.toString().indexOf("Wachtwoord") > -1) {
        ftp.stdin.write("<<password of server>>");
        ftp.stdin.write(os.EOL);
        authenticated = true;
    }
    if(authenticated && !commandsSended) {
        ftp.stdin.write("put " + filePath + " " + newName + "\n");
        commandsSended = true;
    }
});

ftp.on('exit', function(code) {
    if(code > 0) {
        console.log("FTPService closed with error " + code);
    } else {
        console.log("FTPService closed without error");
    }
});
```

This doesn't result in an error, but simply doesn't work. In linux i don't have the problem because i can send the login information as argument with the command. I know that nodejs has it's own module but i need to get it working with the command line (Also other commands need to be performed which will also cause prompts that need to be filled in).

Answer (score 0):

A good practice developing Node applications is to try to make your application as hybrid as possible. When I say hybrid I mean that it should operate identically and seamlessly on the various operating systems it supports. In your case, this means dropping support for the third-party FTP built-in to Windows or Linux and using a FTP client package specifically built for Node.

There are lots of FTP client packages for Node, here's one that's actively developed: [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp).
Another one that got more years on its back is [jsftp](https://github.com/sergi/jsftp) and allows you to hook into the raw FTP socket connection and write arbitrary FTP comnmands to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your point. And i do agree, but the fact is that im trying to make a proof of concept with it working with the command line tool of ftp in windows. Because there are other commands that need to be performed in the same manner. In linux i also encouter the same problem but i can work around in in case of ftp by passing the authentication info in the arguments. But with another command (with a different purpose) i may be encoutering the same problem as in windows.